# MongoDB get all documents, sort by a field and add ordering field based on the sorting

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to sort the result of my mongoDB query and add a ranking based on that sorting. Currently I only call .find().sort({total: 1}) and this gives me the correct ordering of the documents. But is it possible to "add a field" based on that sorting (basically a ranking field, starting from 1 and counting up)? I tried googling but didnt found anything that suits for this purpose.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the numbers are continuous, is there a reason you are not using the index in the results set?

Comment: I want to pass the result to the frontend but I dont know how to add a "rank" attribute to each entry of the query result. For clarification: I have a field "total" in my documents that contains a number. I want to get all documents (with the .find() ), order the results by this field and then add an attribute "rank" (for the frontend). E.g. the highest "total" will have rank 1 etc..

Comment: Hm, I don't know how to do that in mongo offhand (that's not to say there isn't a way, I'm no expert). Should be fairly simple to handle on the frontend though. In js, for example, is as simple as `resultsArray.map((elem, idx) => ({...elem, rank: idx}))`

Comment: I´ll take that as a first version to make it work :) thanks